# How did this make Skype work?

Tags: skype

I came across this solution here that worked for me, and I want to know how did it work and what did it do? Could anybody please explain?

Open the terminal and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf
```

Paste the following line:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
```

Run ldconfig in the terminal:

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Answer (score 3):

It adds the path to the mesa libraries to the library path. The library path contains all locations on the file systems where applications have too look for shared libraries.

The first command adds the location to the library path, the second command refreshes the cache and activates the new location.

Comment: What Skype needs mesa libraries for is a mystery to me though...